# sql FInding strings with duplicate characters

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have a list of strings:

1. HEAWAMFWSP
2. TLHHHAFWSP
3. AWAMFWHHAW
4. AUAWAMHHHA

Each of these strings represent 5 pairs of 2 character combinations (i.e. HE AW AM FW SP)

What I am looking to do in SQL is to display all strings that have duplication in the pairs.

Take string number 3 from above; AW AM FW HH AW.  I need to display this record because it has a duplicate pair (AW).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Will it always be combinations of 2 characters that you would be looking for duplicates in?

Comment: And if you're looking for 'combinations of characters', should this be normalized?  This is suggesting that there is some meaning to _each_ pair of characters, which would make it a multi-value column - something that's usually an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Given current requirements, yes this is dooable.  Here's a version which uses a recursive CTE (text may need to be adjusted for vendor idiosyncracies), written and tested on DB2.  Please note that this will return multiple rows if there is more than 2 instances of a pair in a string, or more than 1 set of duplicates.

```
WITH RECURSIVE Pair (rowid, start, pair, text) as (
                     SELECT id, 1, SUBSTR(text, 1, 2), text
                     FROM SourceTable
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT rowid, start + 2, SUBSTR(text, start + 2, 2), text
                     FROM Pair
                     WHERE start < LENGTH(text) - 1)
SELECT Pair.rowid, Pair.pair, Pair.start, Duplicate.start, Pair.text
FROM Pair
JOIN Pair as Duplicate
ON Duplicate.rowid = Pair.rowid
AND Duplicate.pair = Pair.pair
AND Duplicate.start > Pair.start
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not very elegant solution, but it works and only returns the row once no matter how many duplicate matches. The substring function is for SQLServer, not sure what it is for Oracle.

```
select ID, Value
from MyTable
where (substring(Value,1,2) = substring(Value,3,4)
or substring(Value,1,2) = substring(Value,5,6)
or substring(Value,1,2) = substring(Value,7,8)
or substring(Value,1,2) = substring(Value,9,10)
or substring(Value,3,4) = substring(Value,5,6)
or substring(Value,3,4) = substring(Value,7,8)
or substring(Value,3,4) = substring(Value,9,10)
or substring(Value,5,6) = substring(Value,7,8)
or substring(Value,5,6) = substring(Value,9,10)
or substring(Value,7,8) = substring(Value,9,10))
```